# Keeping an app's internal time in sync

Tags: android, ios

*Disclaimer:* I am a backend developer, and I have no idea of what happens inside an Android or iOS app, so please bear with me.

In a specific use case of our platform we would need all client applications (Android and iOS) to keep an internal timer accurate and in sync with an external source of time (so that they can accurately timestamp messages sent between one another). Is this possible at all (using, for example, an NTP client or a different / better technique)?

Answer (score 0):

When the client connects to the server it can fetch what the server's reference time source is. Once it has obtained this it can calculate and store the difference between the server's time and the device's time. 
Then when the client needs to do something based on the time* on the handset it takes the server's time into consideration when doing whatever it needs to do such as schedule a timer or whatever.

*You can't really do anything based on time in iOS, only if the app is in the foreground. An exception is posting a local notification. Its not possible to schedule a timer for example if the app is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

As per Martin H, you could use an offset from the device's internal time. The client device will probably be within a second of current time if the user has not manually set the time (which does happen - I just read about a user that changed her date/time to tomorrow to get a reward in a game).

I have dealt with this in a time-based app by using the device time. The client and server validate against server time when communicating with the server.

For example, when the client and server communicate, the server can validate the client time against server time. If the user time is off by more than 'x' minutes, the server sends back an error message.

It will be difficult to keep all clients within a few milliseconds of each other. One idea is to use the server to coordinate messages (messages are not sent between devices, but to the server, which then sends the message on). Then, you can use the received time at the server as the basis for the message time.